# What techniques would be use to prove $6x^2 +12x +8$ cannot be perfect cube for integer x > 0

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm wondering if there are any basic techniques.

Comment: Try to reduce the problem until you get an impossible statement. E.g.: This number is even,  hence if it is a cube, it must be divisible by 8. Hence $6x^2 + 12x = 6x(x+2)$ must be divisible by 8. Hence $x = 2k$. And so on.

Answer (score 5):

This is a direct result of Fermat's last theorem if you observe that

$(x+2)^{3} = (x^3) + (6x^2 + 12x + 8)$

Comment: Would you consider the usage of Fermat's Last Theorem a "basic technique" as the OP asks for? (This problem sits at under-high-school level.)

Comment: Well, he is wondering if there are basic techniques. The result itself may be a monster to prove, but once it has been proven, we can use it. So may theorems are used at school level which are not really proved at school level (including area of a circle, or volume of a sphere)

Comment: The answer by Hans is essentially how you prove Fermat's last theorem for case n = 3.  These are only techniques I have heard of other than the super-advanced stuff that proved all cases of n.    So seems we need to know Fermat's last theorem is true or use a type of reduction technique, so called "infinite descent" technique which is what I think Hans was getting at.

Comment: @Alex M.  Fermat's Last Theorem for cubics can be proven via elementary methods.  Hence, I see no problem with Shailesh's solution.

Comment: @Batominovski: Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x,y)$ be any integer solution to $y^3 = 6x^2 + 12x + 8$.

Since RHS is even, so does LHS and $y$. This implies $\text{RHS} \equiv 0 \pmod 8$.
It is easy to check
$$\text{LHS} \equiv 
\begin{cases} 0,& x \text{ even}\\2, & x \text{ odd}\end{cases}
\pmod 8$$
So $x$ is also even. This implies existence of integers $X,Y$ such that $x = 2X$ and $y = 2Y$.
In terms of $X, Y$, we have

$$Y^3 = 3X^2 + 3X + 1 = (X+1)^3 - X^3
\quad\iff\quad X^3 + Y^3 = (X+1)^3$$

By Fermat's Last theorem, at least one of $X, Y$ or $X+1$ is $0$.
This leads to three and only three set of possibilities:

- $X =  0 \rightarrow (x,y) = (0,2)$
- $Y =  0 \rightarrow \text{ no solution}$.
- $X = -1 \rightarrow (x,y) = (-2,2)$

Since all of these have $x \le 0$, $6x^2 + 12x + 8$ is never a cube for $x > 0$.

Comment: Would you consider the usage of Fermat's Last Theorem a "basic technique" as the OP asks for? (This problem sits at under-high-school level.)

Comment: This is what prompted me to ask question.  If you take a x by x by x cube you can make a bigger cube by surrounding it with 1x1 blocks to get a (x+2)*(x+2)(x+2) cube  The difference between the two cubes is 6x^2 +12x +8.  Which by fermat's last theorem cannot be cube.

Comment: @AlexM. yes, I consider Fermat's Last Theorem a "basic technique". It is something  one can understand and use even for the kids (proving it is a completely different manner).